# Reporting an error back to ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have the following code posting my form data to upload.php via ajax. Within the php file, the server checks the uploaded file size/format etc. How can I tell ajax if this has failed and stop the success message from showing?

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'upload.php',
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#getintouch .alert-error').slideUp();
        $('#getintouch .alert-success').slideDown();
        $('#submit').data('loading-text', 'Sent');
        $('#submit').button('loading');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Have the server echo back a message and have the JavaScript check for it.

   ```
   success: function( data ) {
       if ( !data.success ) //if JSON
       {
           // do error message
           return;
       }
   ```
2. Change the HTTP response code

   ```
   http_response_code( 500 );
   ```

   EDIT - use the error parameter on the front end to handle it:

   ```
   error:   function(){...},
   success: function(){...},
   ```

Comment: Just to add: in case of 5xx HTTP code you should use "error" AJAX callback: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

Comment: I used method 2 but the success event is still being triggered despite setting the response code to 500 and setting the script to die();

Comment: Aha! http_response_code requires php 5.4, I am using 5.3. I used the following code instead header(':', true, 500);